# Visual Studio 2015 Natvis thinks QString is an enum instead of a type

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, natvis

In Visual Studio 2015, Update 3, I'm using a customized version of Qt5.natvis (from the old VS Add-In) added to my solution files.  Sometime after adding blocks for QFlags, QString is now getting picked up as an enum.

Natvis tells me `Natvis: C:\projects\core\trunk\Qt5.natvis(703,20): Error: constant "QString" is not a type name`. And when I type `QString` into the debugger watch window, instead of the icon indicating a class, I see `QString(10)` in the Value column, and `QMetaType::Type` in the Type column.

It appears that it may be latching onto an alternate definition of the enum that is #defined out for my build, but verbose logging doesn't tell me how it's finding or parsing headers for the types (although I do often have to explicitly specify the module, especially for private classes.)

Has anyone run into this problem, or know how to dive even deeper into Natvis to find out why it thinks QString is a type all of a sudden?

Comment: I think it would help if you showed the relevant parts of your natvis file.